# error occurs when sending form data to mail using php

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to send or write code for sending an email from a form, but each time i submit, i get an "error occurred" statement that I had specified in the if else statement, hence mail can't be sent. what could be the problem? Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Email Us</title>
  <body>
    <form action="email_us.php" name="quotation" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="first name"><br>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="enter email"><br>
        <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject"><br>
        <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Message"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Request Quotation">
    </form>
  </body>
 </html>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){      
        $fname=$_POST["fname"];
        $email=$_POST["email"];
        $subject=$_POST["subject"];
        $message=$_POST["message"];

         $to = "mymail@email.com";//i changed this for posting purposes.
        $from = $email;
        $headers .= "From: ".$from."\r\n".
                    "Reply-To: ".$from."\r\n".
                    "X-MAILER: PHP/".phpversion();
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
        if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
            echo "mail sent";
        }else{
            echo "error occurred";
        }
      }

?>
```

Comment: Put the php code at the top of the html even before the <html> tag

Comment: you are redirecting  form to page **email_us.php** by using form attribute `action="email_us.php"` if you want to submit form to same page your action attribute  should be `action=''`

Comment: Try printing this in email and see what it is it returning error_get_last();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are we good to assume this code is stored in the file email_us.php?

Maybe change line #25 from:

```
$headers .= "From: ".$from."\r\n".
```

to:

```
$headers = "From: ".$from."\r\n".
```

As this is the first time you define the $headers variable, you don't need to concat the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){      
    $fname=$_POST["fname"];
    $email=$_POST["email"];
    $subject=$_POST["subject"];
    $message=$_POST["message"];

    $to = "mymail@email.com";//i changed this for posting purposes.
    $from = $email;
    $headers .= "From: ".$from."\r\n".
                "Reply-To: ".$from."\r\n".
                "X-MAILER: PHP/".phpversion();
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
    $mail = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)
    if (!$mail) {
       $errorMessage = error_get_last()['message'];
    } else {
       echo('Mail successful send');
    }
  } ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <title>Email Us</title>
     <body>
      <form action="" name="quotation" method="POST">
       <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="first name"><br>
       <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="enter email"><br>
       <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject"><br>
       <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Message"><br><br>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Request Quotation">
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

And you action should be blank or use

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>
```

Comment: Can you paste the error msg in question? So I can say what is causing it

Comment: I added a extra layer of error throw update the code and reply the output

Comment: thanks. it has finally worked.  using this  $headers = "From: ".$from."\r\n".
through this ,
 if (!$mail) {
       $errorMessage = error_get_last()['message'];
       echo $errorMessage;
    }

Comment: A was about to edit my answer that worked for me just before your problem got fixed. Glad that it worked.